# Show that $(x + y\sqrt{-5})$ must be a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Got these problems as separate sections of a question in a book's chapter on 'Divisibility & primes'.

> 1. Show that if $x^2 + 5y^2 =1$, then $x = \pm 1$.

Can state it in terms of two factors as : $(x + y\sqrt{-5})(x-y\sqrt{-5}) =x^2 + 5y^2$, with 
(i) $(x + y\sqrt{-5}) = 1$, 
(ii) $(x - y\sqrt{-5}) = 1$
Adding both (i) & (ii), get: $x = 1$, Subtracting (ii) from (i), get: $(y\sqrt{-5}) = 0$.
Unable to pursue after that, as $x=-1$ is not possible.

> 2. Show that $(x + y\sqrt{-5})$ must be a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

The hint given is to use the unique factorization theorem for the integers, by supposing $(x + y\sqrt{-5}) = (a + b\sqrt{-5})(c + d\sqrt{-5})$. The hint asks to show that: $(x^2 + 5y^2) = (a^2 + 5b^2)(c^2 + 5d^2)$. 
I need some more hint or help to pursue, as squaring $(x + y\sqrt{-5}) = (a + b\sqrt{-5})(c + d\sqrt{-5})$ does not lead to $(x^2 + 5y^2) = (a^2 + 5b^2)(c^2 + 5d^2)$. 
My attempt is stated for squaring both sides below:
L.H.S.: $(x + y\sqrt{-5})(x + y\sqrt{-5}) => x^2 + 2xy(-5) -5y^2$ 
 R.H.S.: $(a + b\sqrt{-5})^2(c + d\sqrt{-5})^2 => (a + b\sqrt{-5})(a + b\sqrt{-5})(c + d\sqrt{-5})(c + d\sqrt{-5}) => (a^2 -5b^2 +2ab\sqrt{-5})(c^2 -5d^2 +2cd\sqrt{-5})$

> 3. Find all primes less than 50 in integers that can be written in the form $x^2 + 5y^2$.

No clue except to first find the primes: $2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47$.

Then trying to see if the factorization works, so starting with $2 = x^2 + 5y^2$, but cannot think further. Do I need to have $y$ as a imaginary number only, as $\sqrt{-5}$, or anything will work.

Comment: In the first part you could also have both i) and ii) equal to $-1$.

Comment: What book is that? Can you at least tell us the year of the first printing?

Comment: Book is less worse than me, a big question with 5-6 sections and the 'needed' line was on the top para. missed by me. Anyway, told the book's name to both the other answers. Main issue was the inability to understand the significance of the question in that chapter seemingly concerned with GCD and primes.

Comment: For 2) you need to assume (at least this is probabyl what the authors intended to ask) that $x^2 + 5y^2$ is a prime number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You're overthinking this one. We have two integers, $x$ and $y$, with $x^2 + 5y^2=1$. If $y$ is anything other than $0$, then $5y^2$ is greater than $1$, and since $x^2$ is non-negative, the equation is impossible. Having decided $y=0$, we are left with $x^2=1$, which has two solutions: $x=\pm 1$
2. This question seems to be missing something. It is not true that every number of the form $x+y\sqrt{-5}$ is prime in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$. For example, we can take $x=1, y=5$, and note that $1+5\sqrt{-5}$ factors as $(3+\sqrt{-5})(2+\sqrt{-5})$.
3. An easier way to do this is to pick values of $y$, and then for each one, try values of $x$ until you pass $50$.

Comment: Regarding second question, can you please elaborate : 'is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$'.

Comment: If an element of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ cannot be written as a product of two other elements of the ring unless one of them is a unit, then it is "prime" in that ring. It's the same definition we use in $\Bbb Z$: the fact that we can "factor" $5$ as $5=(-5)(-1)$ doesn't make it any less prime.

Comment: This ring, $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, is a lot like $\Bbb Z$ in this way: the only units are $\pm 1$. The primes and composites are simply those elements than cannot be factored in the ring, and those that can.

Comment: The second question, as it's stated now, is just like: Show that $n$ must be a prime in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: The book asks further in Q.2. : Prove 'similarly' that $(x - y\sqrt{-5})$ is also a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: Number Theory, by Ramanujachary Kumanduri, Cristina Romero, pg #57.

Comment: I see; that one's not in my collection. There definitely seems to be some context missing. It's certainly true that IF $x+y\sqrt{-5}$ is a prime element of the ring, then so is $x-y\sqrt{-5}$. However, there must be some condition for proving that $x+y\sqrt{-5}$ is prime, other than $x$ and $y$ simply being integers.

Comment: Reviews on Amazon suggest that this book is "riddled with errors". Perhaps we've found one here?

Comment: Please state the additional conditions that should be there to make the question #2 correct.

Comment: There could be many. I have no idea what the authors may have been thinking. Maybe some condition on the values of $x$ and $y$ modulo $5$?

Comment: If you could please state 2 such conditions, it will be very helpful. Instead, you could refer a book that deals from ground-up this topic.

Comment: No, that last thing I said makes no sense. Here's a condition that works: If $x^2+5y^2$ is prime in $\Bbb Z$, then both $x+y\sqrt{-5}$ and $x-\sqrt{-5}$ are prime in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Comment: A good book on this topic, which starts from somewhere pretty elementary, is "The Theory of Algebraic Numbers" by Pollard and Diamond.

Comment: "Elementary Number Theory" by Burton is also good.

Comment: I will be highly thankful for your answer and highly useful comments. I will try to now look into how the modified conditions enable to get a correct question, as given by you, i.e. $x^2 + 5y^2 $ is prime in integers.

Answer (score 3):

Both $x$ and $y$ are drawn from $\mathbb Z$, right?

1. If $x = \pm 1$, then $x^2 = 1$. Then $5y^2 = 0$, so obviously $y = 0$. Okay, I kinda took that backwards. Going forward: if $y \in \mathbb R$, then $y^2 \geq 0$. Therefore, if $y \neq 0$, then $5y^2 > 4 > 1$.
2. Unless there is some restriction on $x$ and/or $y$, this statement is false. Simply choose $x$ and $y$ such that $\gcd(x, y) > 1$. Then $\gcd(x, y) \mid (x + y \sqrt{-5})$. Of course, as Tony showed, $\gcd(x, y) = 1$ is no guarantee either.
3. Try fixing $y = 0$, then... um, that doesn't work, squares can't also be prime. Okay, try fixing $y = 1$, then $x^2 + 5y^2$ gives the sequence 5, 6, 9, 14, 21, 30, 41, from which you cull out 5 and 41. Then fix $y = 2$, giving 20, 21, 24, 29, 36, 45, which gives just 29. No need to bother with $y = 3$ for the specified range. So we've got 5, 29, 41. Just three primes, but that's enough to find http://oeis.org/A033205 in the OEIS.

Answer (score 1):

For 3, the squares modulo $5$ are $-1,0,1$, so the primes are: $5,11,19,29,31,41$.
Question 2 doesn't make sense. Need provide context.

Comment: Q.2 is stated in full detail along with the hint given. In chapter there is nothing of that sort, the next one is of Modular arithmetic.

Comment: I bet you're wrong, jit. What book, please?

Comment: Number Theory, by Ramanujachary Kumanduri, Cristina Romero, pg #57.

Comment: If you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to include @Gerry in it. Anyway, sorry, I don't have that book, so I can't check. But if it really says what you say it says, then aren't you convinced it's nonsense?